# Substituting expressions in sympy

Tags: python, sympy

I am new to `sympy` and can't figure out how to relate symbols and print that relation.

```
import sympy
U, R, I = sympy.symbols('U, R, I')
U = R * I
sympy.simplify(R * I)
```

I would like to print `U` instead of `R * I`.

Here, I am overwriting `U` and I am looking for a way to define a relation between symbols and print the relation instead. Is this possible?

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: You can represent an equality with `Eq(U, R*I)`...is that what you want?

Comment: I tried that, but it appears that sympy is not using the equality to simplify the final expression. If I use `Eq(U, R*I)` and want to print `simplify(R*I)` the `R*I` is not replaced with `U`.

Answer (score 0):

Please read https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/gotchas.html. You are confusing Symbols and Python variables. When you write `U = R * I`, you are overwriting the Symbol `U` that you defined in the previous line. It becomes a Python variable that points to the expression `R * I`. In particular, note that the name of a Python variable has nothing to do with the symbolic variable names used by SymPy. You could have also written `expr = R * I` and used `expr` instead of `U`. SymPy has no way to "know" that `R * I` is in a Python variable named "U" or "expr" or whatever.

If you want `U` to be a symbolic variable, you should leave it that way. Then you can use `Eq` to represent the symbolic equality:

```
>>> U, R, I = sympy.symbols('U, R, I')
>>> Eq(U, R*I)
Eq(U, I*R)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! However, I am not confused about python and sympy variables. I just wanted to show what I want to do. I am looking for a way to define a relation between sympy symbols that are taken into account when printing the final expression. If I define `Eq(U, I*R)` and than call `simplify(I*R)` it prints `IR` and not `U`. You see my problem?

Comment: SymPy doesn't exactly work this way, but you can always replace `I*R` with `U` in any expressions using `expr.subs(I*R, U)` .